# Cannot read property 'getOrCreateGeometry' of undefined

Tags: angular, aframe

I am using [A-Frame](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe) with Angular 2.

The code is simple, showing a curved image:

```
  <a-curvedimage src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Random_pyramids.jpg"
    position="0 2 -20"
    theta-length="72"
    height="2.6">
  </a-curvedimage>
```

Without Angular 2 router, it works well: [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pqmTU1yaISCijItyVytD?p=preview)

After adding router, I got the error below. [issue plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NiqSRd6hduE5yCboTVZs?p=preview)

> VM14540 aframe.min.js:75 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'getOrCreateGeometry' of undefined

[image]

And I found if I remove these two `theta-length="72" height="2.6"` in the issue plunker, it won't through the error.

I want to use `theta-length="72" height="2.6"` and the router together. What may cause this? Thanks

Comment: Do you have any guesses what router would change? The error is because something hasn't initialized with the scene when the geometry is initializing. I don't know how that could happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks the help from @ngokevin @perak @alxhub @DzmitryShylovich on [GitHub](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/1965#issuecomment-253350789).

So like @ngokevin said: the error is because something hasn't initialized with the scene when the geometry is initializing.

The working way is

http://plnkr.co/edit/MkQkrneTXYcZ1w6YFoLm?p=preview

```
<a-scene (loaded)="onLoaded()">
  <a-curvedimage
    *ngIf="show"
    src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Random_pyramids.jpg"
    position="0 2 -20"
    theta-length="72"
    height="2.6">
  </a-curvedimage>
</a-scene>
```

.

```
show = false;
onLoaded() {
  this.show = true;
}
```